# how to make gallery to look like in the link give below?

Tags: android, gallery

I have created a photo gallery with the help of tutorial

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

but now i want to extend my gallery to look like this:

[image]
Answer with the example will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such inbuild view, but here is the way to implement **CoverFlow** kind of view:

1. [Android Coverflow Widget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html)
2. [Android Coverflow Widget V2](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)
3. [android-coverflow](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)